# Reduction formula for $\int \tan^n (2x) \ dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, solution-verification

> Establish a reduction formula for $$\int \tan^n (2x) \ dx.$$

My attempt: let $I_{n}=\int \tan^n (2x) \ dx$,

$$=\int \tan^2 (2x) \tan^{n-2} (2x)dx$$
$$=\int (\sec^2 (2x)-1)\tan^{n-2}(2x)dx$$
$$=\int \sec^2(2x)\tan^{n-2}(2x)dx-\int \tan^{n-2}(2x)dx$$

Let $u=\tan (2x), du=2\sec^2 (2x) \ dx$:

$$=\frac{1}{2}\int u^{n-2}du-I_{n-2} =\frac{1}{2} \frac{u^{n-1}}{n-1}-I_{n-2} =\frac{1}{2n-2}\tan^{n-1}(2x)-I_{n-2}$$

Is it correct?

Comment: The result is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you define each $I_n$ as the antiderivative that's $0$ at $x=0$, your recursion is correct. If the intended antiderivatives are arbitrary, it's correct up to additive integration constants. If each $I_n$ denotes the set of all antiderivatives, the recursion is correct with the convention $f-S:=\{f-g|g\in S\}$, with $f$ ($S$) a function (set of functions).